# Connect to Phoenix Socket with Token and Presence

Tags: sockets, websocket, elixir, phoenix-framework, phoenix-channels

I'm trying to tie together the Phoenix **Channel**, **Token**, and **Presence** modules to add chat functionality to my Phoenix 1.3 application. I haven't been able to get all 3 modules working together. The last error was `connection to websocket closed before handshake`. Now, I'm not getting any errors but it's also not connecting to the socket.

I believe the issue is the "connect" function in the player_socket.ex. ( I have a player resource ). Here is the function:

```
  def connect(%{"token" => token}, socket) do
      case Phoenix.Token.verify(socket, "player auth", token, max_age: @max_age) do
        {:ok, player_id} ->
          player = Repo.get!(Player, player_id)
          {:ok, assign(socket, :current_player, player)}
          {:error, _reason} ->
           :error
      end
  end
```

I'm signing the token in a meta tag in app.html.eex. `<%= tag :meta, name: "channel_token", content: Phoenix.Token.sign(@conn, "player auth", :player_id) %>`

Then in the lobby_channel.ex I'm trying to join the channel:

```
  def join("lobby:lobby", _params, socket) do
    send(self(), :after_join)
    {:ok, assign(socket, :player_id, :current_player)}
  end

  def handle_info(:after_join, socket) do
    push socket, "presence_state", Presence.list(socket)
    {:ok, _} = Presence.track(socket, socket.assigns.current_player, %{
      online_at: inspect(System.system_time(:seconds))
    })
    {:noreply, socket}
  end
```

I read the docs but can't seem to figure out why I'm unable to connect to the websocket with the "current_player" so that I can use Presence to display who is online and the player's names to associate with their chat messages. Any insight is greatly appreciated! I have the repo here:
https://github.com/EssenceOfChaos/gofish

**UPDATE**

I am using a "current_player" plug to store the player struct in the conn as "current_player.

```
%Plug.Conn{adapter: {Plug.Adapters.Cowboy.Conn, :...},
 assigns: %{current_player: %Gofish.Accounts.Player{__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, "players">,
    email: "example@aol.com", id: 6,
```

Here is my updated lobby_channel.ex:

```
  def join("lobby:lobby", _params, socket) do
    send(self(), :after_join)
    {:ok, socket}
  end

  def handle_info(:after_join, socket) do
    push socket, "presence_state", Presence.list(socket)
    {:ok, _} = Presence.track(socket, socket.assigns.current_player.id, %{
      username: socket.assigns.current_player.username,
      online_at: inspect(System.system_time(:seconds))
    })
    {:noreply, socket}
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `player_socket.ex` is fine. You do have a few issues though:

In your `layout/app.eex` template:

`Phoenix.Token.sign(@conn, "player auth", :player_id)` is literally writing an atom `:player_id` instead of the ID of the player. In order to write the ID of the player, you should use `@player_id` and add a plug that assigns the value globally to your `router.ex` like so:

```
pipeline :browser do
  [...]
  plug :fetch_current_user
end

...

def fetch_current_user(conn, _) do
  assigns(conn, :current_player, get_session(conn, :current_player)
end
```

This will make `@current_player` available in all your templates, which you can then use in `app.eex`:

```
<%= tag :meta, name: "channel_token", content: Phoenix.Token.sign(@conn, "player auth", @current_player) %>
```

(you should write this conditionally if `@current_player` isn't `nil` and stop your JS client from attempting websocket connections if it is, btw)

This change will immediately fix your inability to connect to the websocket as long as you've signed in, but you still have one more issue:
`{:ok, assign(socket, :player_id, :current_player)}` in your `loby_channel.ex` is assigning the atom `:current_player` literally instead of using the actual value of the current player's ID, but you don't need this line at all. Instead, in your `:after_join`, you should do

```
{:ok, _} = Presence.track(socket, socket.assigns.current_player.username, %{
  online_at: inspect(System.system_time(:seconds))
})
```

Notice I changed `socket.assigns.current_player` to `socket.assigns.current_player.username`. This is because you cannot assign a struct as a Presence key.

Alternatively you could do

```
{:ok, _} = Presence.track(socket, socket.assigns.current_player.id, %{
  username: socket.assigns.current_player.username,
  online_at: inspect(System.system_time(:seconds))
})
```

and in your `socket.js` you'd use `first.username` instead of `id` inside `renderOnlineUsers`

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer! You were right I was assigning the atom "player_id" and not the actual id. I didn't notice because I was still getting a value for the token. I am connected to the websocket now so I've definitely made some progress :
---
transport: connected to ws://localhost:4000/socket/websocket?token=SFMyNTY.g3QAAAACZAAEZGF0YWEGZAAGc2lnbmVkbgYAcXFphWAB.JzSzRcaWpebtBk2kH5ooeqKr8ez3Lxi8IuyRkuh0qxU&vsn=2.0.0 undefined
---
but the Presence module isn't displaying the online users.  I am trying to use "first.username" in socket.js

Comment: Ah, that's because there's another error I forgot to point out: in your `socket.js` you have `let chatInput = document.querySelector("#chat-input");` but it should actually be `let chatInput = document.querySelector("#chatInput");` as that's how you've written the ID in your template :)

Comment: Now it is displaying a logged in user. Thank you for your answer! If I log in with another browser and register a new account it displays the same user logged in twice, any idea why?

Comment: It must have something to do with me using " @current_player.id" in the meta tag to sign the token

Comment: Are you sure there's an issue? I see two separate users as it should be without changing anything in your repo: https://i.imgur.com/shxViKI.png